# What is the mean of f(x) = $\frac{1}{2} x^2 e^{-x} $ when x > 0?

Tags: probability

My original equation is f(x)=$\frac{1}{2}x^2 e^{-x}$ f0r x > 0.

I *believe* I have found the mgf to be $\frac{1}{(1-t)^3}$ and therefore the mean is the first derivative of the mgf which is $\frac{3}{(1-t)^4}$ calculate at t=0, gives us a solution of 3 for the mean.

However I haven't taken a Calculus class in 20+ years and am unsure if I calculate the mfg correctly in the first place. I have 2 pages worth of calculations as I seem to have needed the integration by parts formula twice. Any validation or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PeterForeman: this might be dumb (im 15) but i think it means the Average rate of change from $0$ to $\infty$ but thats a guess

Comment: The task is to find the mean of the pdf given above.

Comment: If the "mean" here means the *expectation* of a random variable with the probability density $f$, then all you want is $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\, dx$. You do not need the moment generating function.

Comment: @Jack I believe you are right from what I am piecing together in my notes, the mean is the expected value E(X).However the original problem had a hint that the mgf was easier, so that is how I attempted it.

Comment: How did you find the moment generating function in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what you are asking for is that you seek to interpret this function as the pdf of a real-valued random variable with range $[0, \infty)$. That is, let $X$ be such a random variable, and then describe its probability function using the pdf

$$f_X(x) := \frac{1}{2} x^2 e^{-x}$$

and by finding the "mean", it is meant to find the expected value of the random variable, $E[X]$. In that case, the most direct way is to just proceed from the definition:

$$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x \cdot f_X(x)\ dx$$

which in this case becomes

$$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} x^3 e^{-x} dx$$

The easiest way to do this integral is to recognize that the integrand is, after saving the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ from in front, that for the Gamma function,

$$\Gamma(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} x^{s-1} dx$$

with $s = 4$, hence

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(4)$$

and $\Gamma(4) = 3! = 6$ so $E[X] = 3$.

Comment: Can you explain to me where the calculation for the gamma function comes from? I have been too long out of a Calc class and am no longer conversant with these functions and recognizable "shortcuts".

Comment: @MT math: The gamma function is actually defined by that integral, because it provides a smooth/continuous and rather "natural"-looking curve which interpolates the factorial at non-integer values of its input, in particular, $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for integers $n \ge 1$. The proof of this requires some integration by parts, but as a "known quantity", you effectively (if you know it) don't have to go through that machination every time.

Comment: Very nice! Is there a book or some other reference that compiles these types of functions related to their "known quantities"? We were told that Calc 1 was a pre-requisite for the course, but have been expected to come up with these types of "common knowledge" facts throughout the course so far, and I am not finding them to be common knowledge at all. I know they are not in the formula sheets at the beginning of my calc book like some of the other common summations and integrals are, I looked there first.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac12x^3e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x=\left[-\frac12x^3e^{-x}-\frac32x^2e^{-x}-3xe^{-x}-3e^{-x}\right]_0^\infty=0-\left(-3\right)=3$$

Comment: Now I wonder why their hint was that the mgf was easier. This looks like a much nicer process than what I did and validates my solution of 3. Thank you.